# Answering a locked question

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/what-is-damaging-this-finished-oak-surface) is locked and it doesn't have an answer that I believe answers the question about how the problem happened. I believe I can answer why it happened which should lead to a proper solution. It is an old question though so I don't know if it is worth answering at this point. Though I think this issue is relatively common so I answer may help someone. I assume locked questions can be unlocked.

Second question is why was this question locked? I can't see any obvious reason.

Comment: Unlocked so give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I will.